# ID selector styling not applying within a media query

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am trying to apply some styling rule to three #id selectors in a media query however it does not seem to be working. However if I do the same outside the query, it is working fine (but unfortunately I just need that rule for that particular screen size. What i am trying to achieve is to adjust the margins of the `div` according to the image size when the screen size is below 767px (there is a gap on left and right side).

Thank you!

```css
body {
    background-color: #fffffe;
}
.container{
    margin: 0;
}

/** HEADER **/
#header-nav{
    background-color: #5d46ea;
    height: 78px;
    border: 0;
}
#logo-img { /** Logo **/
    background: url(../images/imgonline-com-ua-resize-wU3umxGfKn8Y0H6h.jpg) no-repeat;
    width: 150px;
    height: 62px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.navbar-brand h1 { /** Blog Name **/
    color: #fd9200;
    font-family: 'oxygen', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 10px;
}
#nav-list a {
    color: #fd9200;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #5d46ea;
}
#nav-list a:hover{
    background: #684fff;
}
          
.custom-toggler.navbar-toggler { 
    border: 1px solid rgb(253, 146, 0);
}

.navbar-light .navbar-toggler-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 30 30' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='rgba(253, 146, 0, 1)' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 7h22M4 15h22M4 23h22'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

/** HOME PAGE **/

.container {
    margin-top: 10px;
    
}
.jumbotron {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 2px solid #5d46ea;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #5d46ea;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.row {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

#main-tile, #dessert-tile, #smoothie-tile {
    height: 250px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid #5d46ea;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #5d46ea;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#main-tile:hover, #dessert-tile:hover, #smoothie-tile:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 5px 1px #cccccc;
}

#main-tile {
    background: url(https://via.placeholder.com/360x250) no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}

#dessert-tile {
    background: url(https://via.placeholder.com/360x250) no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}

#smoothie-tile {
    background: url(https://via.placeholder.com/360x250) no-repeat;
    background-position: center;   
}

#main-tile span, #dessert-tile span, #smoothie-tile span {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: #6a6a6a;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: .8;
}

/* END HOME PAGE */

/*************** MEDIA QUERIES ***************/

/** LARGE DEVICE **/
@media (min-width:1200px) {
    .jumbotron {
       background: url(https://via.placeholder.com/1200X675) no-repeat;
        height: 675px;
    }
}

/** MEDIUM DEVICE **/
@media (min-width:992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
 .jumbotron {
       background: url(https://via.placeholder.com/992x558) no-repeat;
        height: 558px;
    }  
}

/** SMALL DEVICE **/
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    .jumbotron {
       background: url(https://via.placeholder.com/768x432) no-repeat;
        height: 432px;
    }  
}

/** EXTRA SMALL DEVICES **/
@media (min-width:767px) and (max-width: 576px){
    .jumbotron {
    background: url(https://via.placeholder.com/768x432) no-repeat;
        height: 432px;
    }  
    #main-tile, #dessert-tile, #smoothie-tile{
    width: 360px;
    margin: 0 auto 15px;
    }
}

/** SUPER EXTRA SMALL DEVICES **/
@media (max-width: 479px) {

#main-tile, #dessert-tile, #smoothie-tile {
    width: 280px;
    margin: 0 auto 15px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-witdth, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Food Blog</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<!-- HEADER -->
 <header>
    <nav id="header-nav" class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-lg">
          
           <div class="navbar-header">
               <a href="index.html" class="float-left d-none d-md-block">
                <div id="logo-img" alt="Logo image"></div>
               </a>
                <div class="navbar-brand">
                  <a href="index.html"><h1>Brand Name</h1></a>
                </div>
            </div>

    <button class="navbar-toggler ml-auto custom-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul id="nav-list" class="navbar-nav ml-auto text-center">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Main</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Dessert</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Smoothie</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
         
    </nav>
    </header>
    
<!--  MAIN CONTENT -->
    
   <div id="main-content" class="container mx-auto">
   
<!-- JUMBOTRON -->
    
     <div class="jumbotron text-center">  <!-- FEATURED RECIPE -->
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/768X432" alt="New Recipe Image" class="img-fluid d-block d-md-none">
     </div>  
     
<!-- TILES BELOW THE JUMBOTRON  -->

 <div id="home-tiles" class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
       <a href="menu-categories.html"><div id="main-tile"><span>Mains</span></div></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
       <a href="menu-categories.html"><div id="dessert-tile"><span>Deserts</span></div></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
       <a href="menu-categories.html"><div id="smoothie-tile"><span>Smoothies</span></div></a>
    </div>
 </div>     
</div>   
   
<!-- END OF MAIN CONTENT -->
    
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This line in your code is the problem:

```
@media (min-width:767px) and (max-width: 576px){ ...
```

In your code this applies to all widths wider than 767 and all widths smaller than 576px. I suppose it should be like this instead:

```
@media (max-width:767px) and (min-width: 576px){ ...
```

...to cover widths between 576 and 767px

ADDITION after comments:

I added this (general) rule:

```
.jumbotron img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Otherwise the image inside the jumbotron would appear at its original size an overflow the jumbotron at smaller screen sizes, therefore also making the whole page wider / forcing a scrollbar.

```css
body {
  background-color: #fffffe;
}

.container {
  margin: 0;
}


/** HEADER **/

#header-nav {
  background-color: #5d46ea;
  height: 78px;
  border: 0;
}

#logo-img {
  /** Logo **/
  background: url(../images/imgonline-com-ua-resize-wU3umxGfKn8Y0H6h.jpg) no-repeat;
  width: 150px;
  height: 62px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.navbar-brand h1 {
  /** Blog Name **/
  color: #fd9200;
  font-family: 'oxygen', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 10px;
}

#nav-list a {
  color: #fd9200;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: #5d46ea;
}

#nav-list a:hover {
  background: #684fff;
}

.custom-toggler.navbar-toggler {
  border: 1px solid rgb(253, 146, 0);
}

.navbar-light .navbar-toggler-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 30 30' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='rgba(253, 146, 0, 1)' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 7h22M4 15h22M4 23h22'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}


/** HOME PAGE **/

.container {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.jumbotron {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 2px solid #5d46ea;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #5d46ea;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.jumbotron img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
.row {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

#main-tile,
#dessert-tile,
#smoothie-tile {
  height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid #5d46ea;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #5d46ea;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#main-tile:hover,
#dessert-tile:hover,
#smoothie-tile:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 5px 1px #cccccc;
}

#main-tile {
  background: url(https://via.placeholder.com/360x250) no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

#dessert-tile {
  background: url(https://via.placeholder.com/360x250) no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

#smoothie-tile {
  background: url(https://via.placeholder.com/360x250) no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

#main-tile span,
#dessert-tile span,
#smoothie-tile span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #6a6a6a;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: .8;
}


/* END HOME PAGE */


/*************** MEDIA QUERIES ***************/


/** LARGE DEVICE **/

@media (min-width:1200px) {
  .jumbotron {
    background: url(https://via.placeholder.com/1200X675) no-repeat;
    height: 675px;
  }
}


/** MEDIUM DEVICE **/

@media (min-width:992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
  .jumbotron {
    background: url(https://via.placeholder.com/992x558) no-repeat;
    height: 558px;
  }
}


/** SMALL DEVICE **/

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .jumbotron {
    background: url(https://via.placeholder.com/768x432) no-repeat;
    height: 432px;
  }
}


/** EXTRA SMALL DEVICES **/

@media (max-width:767px) and (min-width: 576px) {
  .jumbotron {
    background: url(https://via.placeholder.com/768x432) no-repeat;
    height: 432px;
  }
  #main-tile,
  #dessert-tile,
  #smoothie-tile {
    width: 360px;
    margin: 0 auto 15px;
  }
}


/** SUPER EXTRA SMALL DEVICES **/

@media (max-width: 479px) {
  #main-tile,
  #dessert-tile,
  #smoothie-tile {
    width: 280px;
    margin: 0 auto 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-witdth, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Food Blog</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- HEADER -->
  <header>
    <nav id="header-nav" class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-lg">

      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a href="index.html" class="float-left d-none d-md-block">
          <div id="logo-img" alt="Logo image"></div>
        </a>
        <div class="navbar-brand">
          <a href="index.html">
            <h1>Brand Name</h1>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <button class="navbar-toggler ml-auto custom-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul id="nav-list" class="navbar-nav ml-auto text-center">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Main</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Dessert</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Smoothie</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </nav>
  </header>

  <!--  MAIN CONTENT -->

  <div id="main-content" class="container mx-auto">

    <!-- JUMBOTRON -->

    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
      <!-- FEATURED RECIPE -->
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/768X432" alt="New Recipe Image" class="img-fluid d-block d-md-none">
    </div>

    <!-- TILES BELOW THE JUMBOTRON  -->

    <div id="home-tiles" class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <a href="menu-categories.html">
          <div id="main-tile"><span>Mains</span></div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <a href="menu-categories.html">
          <div id="dessert-tile"><span>Deserts</span></div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <a href="menu-categories.html">
          <div id="smoothie-tile"><span>Smoothies</span></div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- END OF MAIN CONTENT -->

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi, that is a great point actually. I noticed it just now, however it is still not applying after correcting it.

Comment: so which of the media query rules does not apply?

Comment: on the same media query (767-576px) I want to apply specific width and margin to #main-tile, #dessert-tile and #smoothie-tile.

Comment: I added another rule now - please see the edited answer

Comment: Hi, thank you for that. Actually I was using several images, all different px, according to screen size. So as the browser shrinks images with different pixels would be used. However my main concern was the extra space on the sides that needs to be adjusted (for the tiles below the jumbotron when the screen is small - mobile version)

Comment: well, you are defining a fixed width for these elements - what do you expect?